# How to get the class type reference by its name in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rtti

I'm actually trying to use Rtti to implent a generic method invoker. It should work like this:

- I'll provide the class name, method name, and arguments
- the invoker will do its work by invoking the specified method of this class

So I need the class reference in order to get its Rtti information and seek for the method I want to invoke.

Is there any way to do that without implementing a class reference list of the classes I want to be working with?

Comment: How are you planning on getting hold of an instance of the class?

Comment: I can instantiate an object whether I get the class reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the class reference using his name you must use the  [`TRttiContext.FindType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/RTTI.TRttiContext.FindType) function passing the Name of the class and the retrieve the instance using the  [`AsInstance`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/RTTI.TRttiType.AsInstance) property and then you can call the constructor of the class.

```
var
  Instance : TRttiInstanceType;
  ctx : TRttiContext;
  mClass : TValue;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;   
  Instance := ctx.FindType(ClassName).AsInstance; //ClassName is something like  'Classes.TStringList';
  mClass := Instance.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(Instance.MetaclassType,[]);

   //do your stuff here


end;
```

Comment: Is there any way to see if I have any instance of this class already instantiated and get this object for use?

Comment: This is for another question, but using the RTTI that is not possible.